# Application performance: database table for dropdown menus vs. population in code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-4

My workplace has gotten the go ahead to (finally) modernize our application. One of the major pushes is to tear apart and redo our database. There has always been something within the database that has baffled me though: we have various tables in the code for populating small, basically unchanging dropdown menus (hair color, eye color, gender, etc.) and the integer primary key to the element in each table is used as a foreign key in the main (fairly large) table. This never made sense to me since it seems there may be some overhead there and our main goal is high performance and maintainability. My question is then twofold:

1. As far as the size of the data getting stored, is there a significant difference in storage size and/or performance for using an integer FK for these tables' relation vs. storing a varchar that will probably top out at length 7 or 8 maybe?
2. Is there a significant performance difference between populating dropdowns from a database table and storing their PK value as an FK in the main table vs. populating the dropdown in our code and simply saving the string value?

When all is said and done our application will be written in C# with .NET 4.0 using MVC4 and the entity framework. Our database will be an MS SQL Server 2012 database. Thanks for the help, sorry if this is a repeat. I couldn't figure out what to search on.

Comment: There are many ways to approach this, and no single right answer (e.g. many people would store gender differently than a list of countries). Caching infrequently changing values and building your lists from that  cache can be an effective way to mitigate performance concerns.

Comment: One thing to consider why it makes sense to keep these lookup tables in the database is for consistency. You have a definition for the lookups in SQL server and if you need to run ad hoc maintenance or reporting queries, those lookup values are available without having to scour config files or (worse) hardcoded values in code somewhere. And, please whatever you do, don't use a string value! Then you have a bunch of records with some word "Refrigerator" then if you want to change it to "Fridge" you now have update data and SQL dependencies, instead of changing one row in a lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like OOO (object oriented overkill). The solution is to abstract to a reasonable level. In this case, if you are "baffled" and it "never made sense", it's probably unnecessary. There is no right or wrong way to do it, but in my opinion, you won't have any problem doing what you described.

1. Of course varchar takes more space than a FK. Calculate the number of records you're planning on storing, and you'll get the size difference. Is is negligible? Probably.
2. If anything, that should be faster than populating from a database.

Answer (score -1):

1) CPU only talk in binary, the closest data in our world is number.
the string/varchar you using, will be translate/map to number when the cpu is crunching them.

so theoritically+logically, using number should be best option

as for whether the performance gain will be "significant", this only is more tangible when you testing on a huge volume of data, you have to measure them.

in db general/best practice, number is recommended as key.

but imo, varchar should be no difference, though you have to be aware the case-sensitivity(collateral) may break your design

so using number will save you alot of unforsee/future/integration problems.

2)
if you are into performance, denormalization is the generally one of the approach.
but you should only go into this if you really need the performance and have no better alternative.

you need to understand why/should you adopt normalization, which generally yield more practical benefits than denormalization.